# Is there any way to change Tax Text on PayPal form using PHP?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using **Paypal** Payment and I need to change **TAX** text.
Currently it Display **Tax** only I want to change it **Tax(10%)**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, this text cannot be changed.

If you want your site to have your own display before reaching PayPal with an option to pay with a Debit or Credit Card as an inline form on your site, use this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

(Also allows PayPal payments to be made without redirecting away from your site, within a small in-context window)

You'll need two server-side routes for the approval JS to call, one to create an order and one to capture it.